# How to secure an API using OAuth Certificate Based Authentication

Tags: servlets, oauth-2.0, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have an web application made using servlet and I have an seperate API for the web application. I want to secure the API with OAuth so that when we use OAuth, a client certificate is sent instead of credentials to the authorization server for verification and after verification the access should be allowed to the API. Is there any ways to implement this authentication. If possible what are the steps should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Client certificate credentials can be used for confidential clients, in either the code flow or the client credentials flow. This type of solution is often used in [financial grade](https://openid.net/specs/openid-financial-api-part-1-1_0.html#confidential-client) setups, where high worth data is involved.

Access tokens issued then contain a `cnf` claim, so that every API call is bound to the strong credential used at the time of authentication. See the [RFC8705](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8705.html) standard for further details.

For a worked end-to-end example that you can run locally, and which covers both the
backend and client behaviours, see [this Curity code example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/mutual-tls-api/). Not all authorization servers support these flows, so check for your provider.

Comment: I wish to implement my own authorization server in servlet. Is it possible? If possible what are the steps should I follow to implement this certificate based authentication?